# SQL in Matlab: Check if date´s are equal

Tags: sql, matlab, ms-access

I have a dataset 1 = Price with the date of the first workday of a month and a dataset 2 = Constistuants with dates of the first of every month:

dataset 1 (dd.mm.yyyy):

```
date          
'03.01.2005'    
'01.02.2005'     
'02.03.2005'    
...
```

dataset 2 (dd.mm.yyyy):

```
  date          
    '01.01.2005'    
    '01.02.2005'     
    '01.03.2005'    
    ...
```

In a subquery i want to check if dataset 2 contains month and year of dataset 1.

Therefore i tried:

```
Select Price.*
from Price
    inner join Constituants on Price.a=Constituants.a
where dateserial(year(Price.Date),month(Price.Date),01)=Constituents.Date
```

But i get the error message

```
Error using COM.ADODB_Connection/Execute
Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception:
Source: Microsoft Access Database Engine
Description: Syntax error in join clause.
```

Edit: My whole query is: (Datum=date)

```
EinJahr=adodb_query(DB, ['Select Price.* from Price inner join Constituents on Price.Isin= Constituants.Isin and dateserial(year(Price.Datum),month(Price.Datum),01)=Constituents.Datum (SELECT distinct Price.Datum as Liste FROM Price WHERE Datum IN (SELECT   MIN(Price.Datum) FROM Price GROUP BY MONTH(Price.Datum), YEAR(Price.Datum)) And Price.Datum between DateAdd("m",-12,#' , x, '#) And #' , x, '#']);
```

And my datasets are:

Price:

```
Isin            Date           Price 
______________  _____________  _________________
'AT0000652011'  '01-Jan-2004'  22,7700000000000 
'AT0000652011'  '02-Jan-2004'  23,0300000000000 
'AT0000652011'  '05-Jan-2004'  23,7000000000000 
'AT0000652011'  '06-Jan-2004'  23,7000000000000 
... 
'AT0000652011'  '29-Jan-2004'  24,3800000000000 
'AT0000652011'  '30-Jan-2004'  24,1900000000000 
'AT0000652011'  '02-Feb-2004'  24,4500000000000 
'AT0000652011'  '03-Feb-2004'  24,2900000000000
```

Constituents:

```
Isin              Datum     
______________    ____________ 

'GB00B1YW4409'    '01.01.2005' 
'DK0010244508'    '01.01.2005' 
'CH0012221716'    '01.01.2005' 
'ES0111845014'    '01.01.2005' 
'NL0000301109'    '01.01.2005' 
'FR0000120404'    '01.01.2005' 
'ES0132105018'    '01.01.2005' 
'ES0167050915'    '01.01.2005' 
'CH0010532478'    '01.01.2005' 
'CH0012138605'    '01.01.2005'
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: You shouldn't use `top` without `order by`, the results are unpredictable without it. You say you use a subquery, please show complete query (currently there is no subquery)

Comment: Are you sure matlab is a dbms? Wiki says it's a language, the error message you wrote indicates the underlying dbms is Microsoft Access, isn't it?

Comment: Ah maybe yes. I´m trying to import data from Access into Matlab via SQL

Comment: @KP4711 I am just asking since you removed the access tag I added to the question ;)

Comment: Both datum in Price & Constituents aren't date fields?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste : Oh. I thought this was generic and the dbms is matlab. I re-edit the access

Comment: @krishKM : Yes. In Access both are set as date-fields

Comment: Price.a=Constituants.a should be Price.Isin=Constituants.Isin? I don't see A in your tables and you cannot alias column names. Besides, if you are using reserved keywords like date please encapsulate them using []

Comment: @krishKM i wanted to simplify my query for you. So i just used a as Isin.

Comment: You haven't joined your subquery, it's just a query followed by another query in brackets.

Comment: LOL don't do that otherwise we don't know if its an error or your spelling mistake issue. like you have Constituants and Constituents!! just copy the damn original query

Comment: Oh. I see. I was trying every part of this big query for itself and then paste it together. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
join Constituents on Price.Isin= Constituants.Isin
```

spelling mistake Constituents & Constituants. Glad you've got it sorted!